# Парсер сайта Selenium

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, веб-сайт

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно подтянуть данные нашел код, переделал но выскакивают ошибки... где и что исправить. Заранее благодарен за ответ ? [Whoscored](https://www.whoscored.com/Teams/30/Show/England-Tottenham)

нужно вытянуть два столбца : имя игроков, рейтинг-в эксель .

```
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.whoscored.com/Teams/30/Show/England-Tottenham'

s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

# web driver goes to page
driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'team-squad-stats'))
    )

Players_list = []
Player_rating = []

for nme in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.player-link span.iconize.iconize-icon-left'):
    Players_list.append(nme.text)
for rat in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.rating_sorted'):
    Player_rating.append(rat.text)
data = {'name': Players_list, 'rating_sorted': Player_rating}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df.to_csv('England-Tottenham.csv')
```

[image: Пример поиска]
[image: Пример поиска 2]
[image: Пример поиска 3]

Comment: Прочите, прежде чем задавать такие вопросы, ("Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример")[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example].

Comment: Да согласен, сложный код, ну может есть добрые люди кто поможет ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.whoscored.com/Teams/30/Show/England-Tottenham'

s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

driver.get(url)    
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'team-squad-stats'))
)
Players_list = [nme.text for nme in
                driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.player-link span.iconize.iconize-icon-left')]
Player_rating = [rat.text for rat in 
                 driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.rating.sorted')] # 'td.rating_sorted'
data = {'name': Players_list, 'rating_sorted': Player_rating}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df.to_csv('England-Tottenham.csv')

                     name rating_sorted
0              Harry Kane          7.56
1       Rodrigo Bentancur          7.32
...
23           Oliver Skipp          6.11
24            Djed Spence          6.00
```